# Failed to save server Auditing settings - Error while enabling auditing in Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, identity

I am trying to enable auditing on `SQL database` in Azure portal, but I am getting below error

> Failed to save Auditing settings for server: xyz-east-sqlserver. The server identity is not correctly configured on server 'xyz-east-sqlserver'. Please re-configure `Identity` on the server.

I executed below command in `PowerShell` and found that `Identity` is not assigned for this database/server.

> Get-AzureRMSqlServer

How do I resolve this? How do I add identity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I add identity?

Make use of below Powershell cmdlet to assign identity to your azure SQL Server:

```
$server = Set-AzureRmSqlServer -ResourceGroupName <SQLServerResourceGroupName> -ServerName <ServerName> -AssignIdentity
```

**For Example:**

```
$server = Set-AzureRmSqlServer -ResourceGroupName "RG01" -ServerName "myserver" -AssignIdentity
```

Enabling Auditing:

```
Set-AzureRmSqlServerAuditingPolicy -ResourceGroupName <SQLServerResourceGroupName> -ServerName <ServerName>
-StorageAccountName <StorageAccountName> -AuditType Blob -ErrorAction Stop
```

Take a look on [Set-AzureRmSqlServerAuditingPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.sql/set-azurermsqlserverauditingpolicy?view=azurermps-6.13.0#description) cmdlet here.

Comment: Great! Worked like charm.